# Attributes in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have these divs:

```
<div class="hat" rel="cap">
<div class="hat" rel="pine">
<div class="hat" rel="mouse">
```

How do I use JQuery to do a "where"?

For example

```
$("div.hat").remove WHERE rel="mouse"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('div.hat[rel=mouse]').remove()
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the attribute selector:

```
$("div.hat[rel]") // to get all <div class="hat"> tags with a rel attribute

$('div.hat[rel="mouse"]') // to get a <div class="hat"> tag with a specific rel attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the attribute selectors such as the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for this type of selection. For example:

`$('div.hat[rel=mouse]').remove();`

There are a number of other variations of the attribute selector to do things like matching an element whose attribute begins with, ends with, or contains a certain value. Check out all the [Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) at the jQuery API and familiarize yourself with them.